# Pandas Value error

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

```
from __future__ import print_function
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("volvo_volvo.csv");
dfw = pandas.DataFrame(data = df, columns=['x','y'])
y = df.y.values
x = df.x.values

data = pd.DataFrame({'x' : x, 'y' : y}) #to merge the two side by side
print(data)

formula = 'y ~ x'

mod1 = smf.glm(formula=formula, data=data, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
x = mod1.summary()

print(x)
```

Error:ValueError: The first guess on the deviance function returned a nan.  This could be a boundary  problem and should be reported.

data being brought in from the csv file columns:

```
        x      y
0   50000  16000
1   43000  15000
2   32424  18299
3   92821  14000
4   50392  19000
5   23941  19521
6   29201  20192
7   50192  15291
8   30201  19392
9   20591  18282
10  50401  19294
11  69401  16263
12  22124  16392
13  14940  19583
```

Comment: please provide a full error backtrace, because it's not clear which line of your code throws this exception. My wild guess it's a line: `y = df.y.values`

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the difference between `df`, `dfw` and `data` data frames?

Comment: What are your `y` values? What's the difference to the previous question?

Comment: my data now comes from a csv

Comment: @MaxU, added data which is being input, um not sure what the difference is , i just know they work haha sorry

Comment: I don't know if it is related to the error but you are trying to fit a binomial model on a numerical response (`y` is not binary). Why are you using `families.Binomial`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ayhan using x to predict y